# web font icons (@font-face) in bootstrap are not smooth when viewed in firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, font-face, webfonts

I am using an icon set from fontastic.me, implemented with CSS @font-face in a bootstrap-based design.

The problem is that whenever the icons are inside the bootstrap theme, they are not smooth in appearance when viewed in Firefox. When viewed in Firefox on a plain non-bootstrap page, they appear smooth.

When viewed in Chrome, they appear smooth both inside and out of bootstrap.

This leads me to believe that there's a piece of code required to render the icons smoothly that's missing in bootstrap, or something overwriting it. Obviously posting the entire bootstrap code here is not an option so I am hoping that someone has faced a similar issue and knows a solution.

Here is what they look in boostrap with Firefox:

[image: bs]

And what they look like in Firefox outside bootstrap or in and out of bootstrap with Chrome:

[image: non_bs]

And here is the way they are included:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "minicons";
  src:url("fonts/minicons.eot");
  src:url("fonts/minicons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("fonts/minicons.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("fonts/minicons.svg#minicons") format("svg"),
    url("fonts/minicons.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[data-icon]:before {
  font-family: "minicons" !important;
  content: attr(data-icon);
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```